# Social media related vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-request

How can we say the verb 'post,' as in 'I posted this on Instagram?'

Similarly, what is the noun used for 'post,' as in 'I saw your Facebook post?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`post(verb)` `올리다`
인스타그램에 이걸 올렸어

However, `post(noun)` has many variants.
`글`: 니가 페이스북에 올린 글을 봤어
`게시물`: 니가 페이스북에 올린 게시물을 봤어
`포스트`: 니가 페이스북에 올린 포스트를 봤어

Basically, they are all same meanings.

Comment: What word for post as a noun is most common?

Comment: @Taylor I think '게시물' is most less used one, others have almost same usage.

Comment: @Taylor “글” is the most common and as handy to use as a “post.”